# Ning's AsyncHttpClient builds Futures way too slow (in this case)

Tags: java, asynchttpclient, ning

In my code there is loop which builds the Futures, which is way to slow. It takes about hundreds of milliseconds to build just 1 Future. I'am just talking about setting up the Future object and not about getting the Reponse. Here's the code:

```
while(settings.getCrawlerQueue().size() < settings.getCrawlerQueueSize()) {
    Task task = taskQueue.poll();
    task = setFutureInTask(assignment, task);
}
```

And the `setFutureInTask()` code:

```
public Task setFutureInTask(String assignment, Task task) {
    task.setParserAssignment(assignment);
        switch(assignment){

        case "stuff":
            task.setFuture(asyncClientStandard
                        .prepareGet("http://"+task.getDomain())
                        .execute()
                    );
            break;
[...]
```

I tried different Java JDKs and versions as suggest in some stuff that I read (can't find it :/ ), but that doesn't help. Also tried `JDKAsyncHttpProvider` instead of the default `NettyAsyncHttpProvider`, which is way faster, but also provides very much Flase-Negatives (it seems to cancel very(!) often valid domains).
What I have noticed is: I live in Germany and german .de-domains are noticeable faster than domains from orther countries like Spain.

Any wild guess is highly appreciated! :)

```
[EDIT]
```

Simply switching to another DNS server solved the problem.

Comment: I haven't personally tested out the Async HTTP client, but have you tried koush's `AndroidAsync`? [link](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced a similar (if not identical) issue while writing and experimenting with my HTTP load test plugin. The name resolution seems to take place *synchronously* while creating the future, and if your DNS caching is not working properly, you pay for the whole DNS lookup roundtrip each time.

As to how to *fix* this issue, it is very difficult to say. I would usually just switch to another network interface which wouldn't show this problem.

Comment: The "DNS lookup roundtrip" thing makes very much sense, there's a DNS problem currently at my ISP. What do you mean exactly by "switch to another network interface"?

Comment: In my case I have the option to go through the corporate network or through WiFi with a direct DSL link.

Comment: Simply switching DNS servers helped :D